# how do I check if my textbox is empty and run a function javascript,html

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

i need to run the function `changePageTitle()` if the textbox with the ID "title" is empty and if not then run `newPageTitle = "please choose title" document.title = newPageTitle;`
here is my code (I am trying to make something that changes the title of the page to what ever I put in the text box)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    please choose title
  </title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="title" size="150" oninput="changePageTitle()">
  <br>
  <button onclick="changePageTitle()">
    *click me if page title doesn't change
  </button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changePageTitle() {
      newPageTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
      document.title = newPageTitle;
    }
const interval = setInterval(function(){
  //here is where I want to put the check
}, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok and what's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the variable directly; you already have an event handler which will be fired on input so `setInterval` is unnecessary.

```js
function changePageTitle() {
  let newPageTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
  if (newPageTitle === '') {
    newPageTitle = "please choose title";
  }
  document.title = newPageTitle;
}
```

Try it:

```js
function changePageTitle() {
  let newPageTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
  if (!newPageTitle) {
    newPageTitle = "please choose title";
  }
  document.title = newPageTitle;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    please choose title
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="title" size="150" oninput="changePageTitle()">
  <br>
  <button onclick="changePageTitle()">
    *click me if page title doesn't change
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(document.getElementById("title").value == ''){
     newPageTitle = "please choose title";
     document.title = newPageTitle;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```
document.getElementById("title").value == ''
```

Will return true if the input is empty.

Is that what you're after?